# What is the best way to deal with Typescript incomplete type definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Very often when referencing the `xxx.d.ts` type definition files, there are some methods or functions that I want to use missing in the definition. What is the best way to complete them so I can transpile my ts scripts successfully?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Comment: Well, the best way to handle that is go to the incomplete type definition, fill add the missing things and submit a PR. Until the PR is merged you can use the method mentioned by @NitzanTomer